# Jquery animation in a AngularJS controller or directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, trigger.io, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-controller

I have an app in AngularJS and in one of my view I want to implement some JQuery animation..nothing too fancy..just hide/slide of a divs ..those divs are created from ng-reapet loop and I need access to DOM elements in order to write my JQuery . Where shall I put my code controller or directive ? An exemple of my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".motivation").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();

});
$(document).on("click", ".more", function(){
    $(this).parent().next().slideToggle();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: If you are using angular then you shouldn't be using jQuery to bind click events on your DOM, you should do it the angular way and use ng-click in your HTML.

Comment: And for the animation you should check this out: http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/04/animation-in-angularjs.html

Comment: Yep I use the exemple from your site and it worked straight way with no effort - thanks a lot and beautiful website u got ! :)

Comment: The website sure is nice but it is not mine, I just found it on google :)

Answer (score 3):

With the beta version of AngularJS, you can use `ng-animate`.

[documentation](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.4/docs/api/ng.directive%3angAnimate)

[nganimate.org](http://www.nganimate.org)